# How to get current or last known location without enabling location service on android device?

Tags: java, android, android-location, android-loadermanager, android-developer-api

How to find current or last known location in various mode. 
1. High accuracy mode, 
2. Battery saving mode, 
3.Device only mode. 
4. location Service Off state.

I can able to find location use Google Api 1,2. 
I need also find location 3,4 also. Is their any way to find location with minimum accuracy. thanks.

Comment: not possible with >= KITKAT, you get network location < KITKAT without enable GPS location(in this case you have to enable network location).